# Laptop audio deactivates itself

Tags: laptop, audio, speakers, sound-card

I have an 9-year-old Toshiba Satellite laptop running Windows 10. The PC has one annoying issue, which is that sometimes the audio speakers deactivate themselves. To be more precise, I am e.g. watching a video (either online or locally) and the audio stops coming through the speakers. When this happens, the volume of the audio doesn't change, i.e. it stays at the same volume level as before. Increasing/decreasing the volume or disabling and re-enabling the audio does not fix the issue.

I found two ways to make the speakers work again:

1. Right click on the volume icon on the taskbar and open the Sound settings of Windows. When the Sound setting windows opens, the speakers start working again. Closing the Sound settings window also makes the speakers work again;
2. Plugging (and unplugging) headphones on the audio jack. If I keep the headphones plugged, I can perfectly hear the audio, even if the speakers were not working before plugging the headphones

From the two points mentioned, it seems as if the speakers start working again when the system thinks there is a change/event on the Sound settings. Note, however, that even after these two workarounds, the speakers stop working again after some minutes, sometimes even less than one minute. Also, note that this issue does not happen at all if I am listening to the audio with my headphones.

EDIT: Following a comment, I checked whether the same issue is happening with Ubuntu Live. I can confirm that it is happening exactly the same way as in Windows 10, however, the two fixes mentioned above do not work on Ubuntu Live

Any idea on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: When this happens, if you plug the headphones, do you hear audio in headphones? Try system restore if available and if feasible. Also try rollback of Audio driver thru Device Manager (If rollback option is available, not grayed out). Did Windows update itself recently?

Comment: @patkim I have edited the question to include the answer to your question. This issue has been there for at least one year actually, so it is not related to updates, but I thought about posting the question here only now as I am using more often this PC. Rollback is grayed out

Comment: Check if there are any new drivers (Chances are less as it's 9 year old). Run Live Linux off USB for sometime and recheck if the issue persists with Linux. Take required backup wherever necessary and do a reset/refresh Windows 10 and check if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I checked for new drivers but there are none. I will try with Linux live off USB and I will let you know. A fresh Windows 10 install is indeed the last resort but I would like to avoid it if possible

Comment: @patkim I followed your suggestion and found out that the same thing happens on Ubuntu Live. There is one difference though: after plugging and immediately unplugging the headphones, the audio from the speakers is not restored. Opening the Sound settings does not bring the audio back either (but I guess this is due to how Windows and Ubuntu manage the events differently). I confirm that, also in Ubuntu Live, if I plug in the headphones I can hear perfectly the audio. The problem is with the speakers then, any guess on what might be wrong?

Comment: From your observations it appears that the Jack Sensing mechanism implemented in the Audio system might be failing.This could be at a hardware level too. It seems that it cuts the sound to speakers assuming that headphones are plugged in. If possible just check if you can clean the audio-out port using IPA (IsoProply Alcohol). You may use a spray bottle and spray some IPA cleaner into the port. It might help dissolve and remove any dust or such accumulation that might be causing this misbehavior. This is very preliminary though. May or may not help. No harm in trying though.